# Count number of nan values on a matrix with strings

Tags: python, numpy

I want to count the number of 'nan' values per column inside a matrix full of string values. Like this one:
m:

```
    [['CB_2' 'CB_3']
 ['CB_1-1' 'CB_4-1']
 ['CB_1-2' 'CB_4-2']
 ['CB_2-1' 'CB_5-1']
 ['CB_2-2' 'CB_5-2']
 [nan 'CB_6-1']
 [nan 'CB_6-2']]
```

I tried using `np.count_nonzero(~np.isnan(m)` but it seems to work only with numerical values. Perhaps if I convert it into an empty string or zero (?).

Also, I created a sample numpy array with strings (to try several options) `(np.array([['a','b'],['c','d'],['e','f'],['e','g'],['k','ñ'],['w','q'],['y','d']]))` but when I use `np.nan` it doesnt seems to works correctly since it adds the `nan` value as a string (`'nan'`).

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can transform the array into something numerical (I could not reproduce array with nans, but you can make function to return 0 for non-strings):

```
def f(x):
    if isinstance(x, str):
        if x == 'nan':
            return 0
        else: 
            return 1
    return 0

vf = np.vectorize(f)
```

```
x = np.array([['CB_2', 'CB_3'],
 ['CB_1-1', 'CB_4-1'],
 ['CB_1-2', 'CB_4-2'],
 ['CB_2-1', 'CB_5-1'],
 ['CB_2-2', 'CB_5-2'],
 [np.nan, 'CB_6-1'],
 [np.nan, 'CB_6-2']])
```

```
>>> x
array([['CB_2', 'CB_3'],
       ['CB_1-1', 'CB_4-1'],
       ['CB_1-2', 'CB_4-2'],
       ['CB_2-1', 'CB_5-1'],
       ['CB_2-2', 'CB_5-2'],
       ['nan', 'CB_6-1'],
       ['nan', 'CB_6-2']], dtype='<U6')
```

```
>>> vf(x)
array([[1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 1]])
```